# Create conditionals from bitoperations

Tags: c, assembly, x86, simulation, processor

I'm being tasked with writing a simulator for a very simple microarchitecture (it uses a subset of x86). Since a machine can't do conditionals natively, I'm not allowed to use if/else statements in the code for the simulator. Eg if(opcode){val a = %rax} is not allowed. However I'm told that the functions in the attached header file can simulate the behaviour of conditionals.

I already have a way of determining which opcode is used, however I don't know how to run the appropriate code afterwards.

How can I simulate the behaviour of conditionals using the provided functions?

```
/*
  Elementary functions for digital logic simulation

  All functions declared here corresponds to wire connections.
  No "real" computation is being carried out by them.

  A single wire, when used as a control signal, is represented by the type 'bool'
  Multiple wires, or a single wire not used as a control signal, is represented
  by the type 'val'
*/

#ifndef WIRES_H
#define WIRES_H

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// A generic bitvector - max 64 bits, though. By accident sufficient for our needs :-)
typedef struct { uint64_t val; } val;

// A pair of bitvectors - used by zip() and unzip()
typedef struct {
    val hi;
    val lo;
} hilo;

// simple conversion
val from_int(uint64_t);

// unzip pairwise into two bitvectors holding even/odd bits
hilo unzip(val);

// zip a pair of bitvectors into one.
val zip(hilo);

// pick a set of bits from a value
// lsb: index of least significant bit
// sz: size
val pick_bits(int lsb, int sz, val);

// put sz least significant bits from val at position lsb in result.
// rest of result is 0.
val put_bits(int lsb, int sz, val);

// pick a single bit from a value
bool pick_one(int position, val);

// reverse the order of bytes within value
val reverse_bytes(int num_bytes, val value);

// sign extend by copying a sign bit to all higher positions
val sign_extend(int sign_position, val value);

#endif
```

Comment: Can your architecture branch?

Comment: What exactly are you doing? Trying to use these functions to code the conditional jumps etc. that x86 has and uses for most branching logic or to implement something else without them? You can avoid branches in various places using bit masks with AND to mask out the "didn't take this branch"

Comment: I tought it was clear, sorry chux.
I can restate the question as: "How can I simulate the behaviour of conditionals using the provided functions?"

Comment: By doing the operation that the processor would do in your simulated registers and RAM, setting the appropriate flags, and then testing those flags. A processor simulator needs to be a *model* of it.

Comment: nullp0tr, the architecture has some conditional branching opcodes, however I need to simulate the physical aspect of the machine to use these opcodes.

Comment: You want to implement for example the conditional jumps like `je`, `jne`, `jz`, etc.? If so that makes more sense as it is a question of manipulating the instruction pointer to execute next based on various flag registers.

Comment: "_Since a machine can't do conditionals natively_" Eh!?  That is kind of what makes a computer a computer and not a calculator.  What could you possisbly mean!?

Comment: @Clifford it is true they are not the same as in a C statement, they are testing the side-effect of an operation via the flags register.

Comment: The thing is, in my code I can't use conditionals. Eg if(opcode){ val a =  %rax} is not allowed. So I need a way (using the provided functions) to handle opcodes. I allready have a way to set a flag if a certain upcode is used.

Comment: Depends how you look at it, if i did `instruction_ptr = (zero_flag & jump_arg) | ((~zero_flag) & (instruction_ptr + 1))` then I didnt use `if`, etc. and could be done directly with some logic gates for example (here I assumed for C `zero_flag` if all 1's or 0's width of the pointer, and `+ 1` instruction is complex in x86 encoding).

Comment: The conditional jump/branch instructions of any processor branch depending on the status of condition code register (various names), the condition flags are set depending on the result of a previous operation.  So for example a `jz` branch is taken if the Z flag is set.

Comment: When simulating the hardware surely it is legitimate to have for  say `JZ` : `if( (CCR & ZFLAG) == ZFLAG ) PC = address_argument ;` - that is not the same as `if( ACCUMULATOR == 0 )  PC = address_argument;` since it simulates the hardware operation more closely.

Comment: The fact the code he has is talking about `wire connections` Im thinking maybe the simulator is at least a prototype for something not running on a general CPU and that it will need to manipulate its registers with simple bit and arithmetic operations in a loop. But still not really clear...

Comment: The assignment in itself is quite badly formulated/explained. However I think I've figured it out. One of the other 57 header files we've been handed includes the function 'use_if' and I think I can use that. Sorry for wasting your time :/
Can anybody close the question?

Comment: Can you use `goto`? it can do simular things to `if/else` blocks and it more simple for machines.

Comment: I don't think I'm allowed to, the essence of the assignment is to learn how a machine works on a physical level.

Comment: Real machines do have conditional-branch instructions in asm.  `if(x) { stuff; }` is just convenient high-level syntax for `cmp x, 0` / `je skip_over` / stuff.  (So you conditionally branch over the `if` body, based on the opposite condition from the high-level source.)  Just look at compiler output like https://godbolt.org/z/_v0NiP for x86 and AArch64 for branchy or branchless code.  Also, why would your *simulator* need to be written with the same restrictions as the machine it's simulating?  It's supposed to be self-hosting, so it could simulate itself?

Comment: @Peter But here I think he is trying to implement the instructions in a way comparable to the electronic circuits and the implementation of that is just like `while (true) instruction_ptr->exec()` (or program counter), with no recursion on `exec`. @limeattack is that the right line of thinking, and you have a loop that which decodes and executes instructions in sequence?

Comment: @FireLancer: Yeah, it sounds something like that.  I'm still unclear why the simulator is restricted to things that the simple target machine can do.  If you want silly computer tricks, x86's `mov` instruction is Turing-complete if you slap a loop around it, or fill a 64k real-mode segment so you get wrap-around of IP back to `cs:0`.  The computation is done using `+` in addressing modes, and lookup tables, though.  https://github.com/xoreaxeaxeax/movfuscator

Comment: @Peter But that is stuff the x86 can do, what he is trying to *make* I think. Although thinking about it with my zero-cpu design skill, if I take a 32bit register cell and call it `IP`, then `JE` should be able to output a 32bit address (IP + relative offset) plus a single bit "conditional" on if the register should actually set that or not. Maybe that is what the mentioned `use_if` does.

Comment: Yeah, you could describe JE as `EIP =  ZF ? EIP+rel32 : EIP` I guess.  Earlier pipeline stages need to resteer to a new fetch address, but sure in a non-pipelined CPU.  I don't think that models data-flow through gates very well, like an FGPA or something, though.

Comment: Well I was thinking more like, `set_eip_if(ZF, EIP+rel32)` which in x86 is as you say, going to be an `if` or ternary, but from the little electronics I did would be the enable input on the register and it captures the input on say the rising edge (like a set of D flip-flops), which is easier than trying to keep the input bits stable all the time.